# What are the differences between the touch controls of an iPad and an iPad emulated in Chrome Developer tools?

Tags: ipad, google-chrome-devtools

I seem to frequently get different behavior in the way an element responds to user input on an actual iPad compared with the Chrome Developer Tools Device Emulated iPad.

Are there any documented differences between actual iPads and Chrome Emulated iPads? I'm most interested in the differences between how they handle input of touch gestures. I'm aware that multitouch is severely limited (since I only have one mouse cursor).

I wish I could give you an example, but everything I've dealt with in this regard is proprietary. If anyone can provide a good example, I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This site seems to have some answers to this question: https://mobile1st.com/why-chrome-devtools-is-inaccurate-for-mobile-testing/ I'm reviewing it now. I'll post an update when I'm done.

I found this interesting, but I don't think it's different in the emulator, iOS requires the user to double tap on anchor references, as detailed here: https://css-tricks.com/annoying-mobile-double-tap-link-issue/ but the Chome Dev Tools Emulator has no such requirement.

So while this article does a reasonable job of pointing out that the rendering engine differences can result in very different renders of the same page, it does not discuss user input at all so it's not what I'm looking for. It's also mostly a sales pitch for their product, which, while I'm sure it's nice, doesn't seem to address my concern.

I've found this: http://sitr.us/2011/07/28/how-mobile-safari-emulates-mouse-events.html which states that if there are mouseover events present, they will be called instead on the first tap. Removing mouseover events seems like the right thing to do here.

"Ultimately, I think seeing hover states fade away will make the web a better place. There never has been any substitute for concise content, clear interaction, and simple design. If we focus on core elements that make browsing the web great, our sites will function properly no matter how people use them." - Trent Walton